# React SPA in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes, single-page-application

Am developing a nextjs application where i need to use react routing system in the dashboard rather than the nextjs default routing system. The nextjs documentation gives hope that i can achieve this but it is shallow and has no clear and complete code samples.

https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-create-react-app#single-page-app-spa

Can someone direct me to a source that explains this clearly.

I want to achieve this in;
"next": "12.1.6",
"react": "18.1.0",

Thank you

Comment: Check this out. It might work for you: https://github.com/colinhacks/nextjs-react-router

Comment: Thanks @brc-dd for your answer. However, this approach converts the whole app to behave as an SPA. The functionality i need is to have some public pages use the next routing system but have react routing system in the dashboard.

Comment: _"i need to use react routing system in the dashboard rather than the nextjs default routing system"_ - can you elaborate on why you need to do that? Next.js routing behaves like SPAs routing during client-side navigations.

Comment: @juliomalves its just that i have found react routing system to work very well in dashboards where i have many links in one page and the transition to different pages is smooth since only specific components change. I have already implemented the nextjs client routing using the Link component. However, every link navigation in the dashboard seems to like fetch a new document which makes the dashboard to flicker. Its not a big deal for me, i just want to know whether i can achieve the smooth transition in a nextjs dashboard without fetching a document whenever i click a different link.